# What is the scancode for spacebar?

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to figure out what the scancode for the spacebar key is.

- According to the [USB specification](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf) (page 54) it's 44
- According to `showkey` and `evtest` it's 57
- According to `xev` it's 65
- According to [KeyBoardStateView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/keyboard_state_view.html) it's 32 (thanks DrMoishe!)

So which one is it? And why are all these numbers different?

Comment: Does 0x3d work?

Comment: Yet another number! Where did you get this one from?

Comment: Scancodes differ, https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html , depending on the hardware. The key codes themselves are more standardized (ASCII, EBCDIC, etc.), and you can seet them with a utility such as https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/keyboard_state_view.html

Comment: Then let's assume the hardware is either a builtin laptop keyboard or a plugged-in USB keyboard (which is where I got these numbers from).

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-179-Manually-Forcing-a-Crash-Dump Resources screenshot

Comment: Here is a command for you: `dispdiag -testacpi`

Answer (score 1):

**For USB and laptop keyboards the scan code for spacebar is 44**.

So where do these other numbers come from? Before USB, there were PS/2 keyboards whose scan codes were different depending on the "scan code set" used by the keyboard ([source](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-10.html#correspondence)):

- Spacebar according to PS/2 scan code set 1: `57`
- Spacebar according to PS/2 scan code sets 2 and 3: `41`

To smooth over these differences, operating systems convert scan codes to more universal *key codes*, which are the same regardless of whether a USB or PS/2 keyboard is used. However, different operating systems do this differently:

- Windows key code for spacebar: `32`
- MacOS key code for spacebar: `49`
- Linux key code for spacebar: `57`

Note that the Linux key code for space is 57, which happens to be the same as the PS/2 scan code set 1 (even for USB keyboards!). However, Linux has one more abstraction layer called X, which uses its own set of key codes. The X key code for spacebar is 65.

For more background information about PS/2 keyboards, visit the [OSDev wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/PS/2_Keyboard) or watch [this video by Ben Eater](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7aXbh9VUB3U) about the PS/2 protocol. I have made this answer a community wiki in the hope that others will contribute more sources, specifically for USB keyboards.